# Буква русского алфавита

Tags: алфавит

В олимпиаде был предложен вопрос:
Российская академия наук во времена царствования Екатерины Второй приступила к созданию энциклопедии. Однажды императрица спросила академиков об их работе. Выслушав ответ учёных, государыня сказала, что пора оставить покой и работать усерднее.
 О словарных статьях на какую букву шёл разговор?
Среди вариантов ответа:ять; ижица; ер,еры,ерь; а также д;и,й;ц;к;с;э;ж;в;т;ф;е,ё;и;н;я;о;а;б;п;г;л;п;м;ш;х;у;ю;р;ч;щ.
Я не смогла ответить на этот вопрос, но очень хочется знать ответ. Мне кто-нибудь может помочь?

Answer (score 4):

Буква П называлась, если не ошибаюсь, "Покой".

Comment: Да. Именно так. Интересно  только, сколько самых неожиданных букв-кандидатов предложено автором. Это несколько настораживает, но другой версии нет.

Answer (score 3):

Это очень просто) правильный ответ — *П*.
В старой азбуке буквы назывались словами на эту букву. представьте себе, как будто вы диктуете кому-то по телефону с плохой связью по буквам, например, свою фамилию. И вот сейчас нужно «изворачиваться» и придумывать слова на каждую букву, чтобы вас услышали, а раньше название каждой буквы и так звучало как слово: азъ, буки (иногда говорят «букЫ»), веди, глаголь, добро и т.д.  Буква *П* в этой азбуке как раз и называлась «покой». Более того, у кого-то из классиков есть выражение «столы стояли покоем» (попросту говоря, буквой «П»).
Некоторые даже пытаются читать алфавит как единое целое и находить в нём некое «послание к славянам». Такое искушение возникает, поскольку некоторые части алфавита действительно можно прочитать как связный текст (глаголь добро есть; како люди мыслете; наш он (Бог?) покой; рцы слово твердо и т.д.).